# сохранение в столбик

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Как сделать чтобы сохранение было в столбик, а не в строчку ??

```
<?php
$file= "log.txt";
$data = date("d.m.Y"); 
$time = date("H:i");    
$ip = trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$agent = trim($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 

if(isset($file)){ 
$fo = fopen($file, 'a+');
$res = "$data|$time|$ip| \n"; 
$fw = fputs($fo,$res);
fclose($fo); 

    echo "";  
} 
else{ 
    echo ""; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: $res = "$data|$time|$ip| " + PHP_EOL;

Comment: счас выяснится, что пишите под линуксом, а смотрите в блокноте в винде, который `\n` отдельный не воспринимает

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы!

---

вот так нужно:

```
$res = "$data|$time|$ip| ".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: а чем это отличается от предыдущего ответа? напишите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

если написать - `$res = "$data|$time|$ip| " + PHP_EOL;`
сохраняет только дату и всё. и тоже в столбик.